# Como aplicar onmouseover y onmouseout en el mismo elemento

Tags: javascript, html, div

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que tengo que cambiar el texto al pasar el ratón por encima de un `<div>` y, cambiarlo de nuevo al quitarlo de encima. Pues bien, cada evento funciona perfectamente de forma individual. Pero al tener los dos solo funciona el `onmouseover`.

¿En qué me equivoco?

Muchas gracias!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
             Id officiis, doloremque, eius quam consequuntur voluptas 
             quidem iste deleniti eaque unde ad consequatur. Consequatur
              nostrum nobis facere veniam! Ut, sapiente repellat.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var bloque = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        function cambiar(){
            bloque.innerHTML = "<p>Tengo el ratón encima!</p>";
        }

        function cambiar2(){
            bloque.innerHTML = "<p>Gracias por quitármelo</p>";
        }

        bloque.onmouseover = cambiar;
        bloque.onmouseout = cambiar2;


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolverlo en lugar de usar `innerHTML` usa `textContent`, con `innerHTML` estas modificando también el comportamiento del elemento `<div>`.

Observa el código funcionando:

```js
var bloque = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    function cambiar(){
        bloque.textContent= "Tengo el ratón encima!";
    }

    function cambiar2(){
        bloque.textContent = "Gracias por quitármelo";
    }

    bloque.onmouseover = cambiar;
    bloque.onmouseout = cambiar2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
         Id officiis, doloremque, eius quam consequuntur voluptas 
         quidem iste deleniti eaque unde ad consequatur. Consequatur
          nostrum nobis facere veniam! Ut, sapiente repellat.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias por una explicación tan clara

Comment: de nada @ÁlvaroGarcía que tengas buen día.

Answer (score 1):

Si le das altura al `div`, funciona correctamente.

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
         Id officiis, doloremque, eius quam consequuntur voluptas 
         quidem iste deleniti eaque unde ad consequatur. Consequatur
          nostrum nobis facere veniam! Ut, sapiente repellat.</p>
</div>
```

Si usas los eventos `onmousenter` y `onmouseleave` evitas un pequeño parpadeo que se nota cuando mueves el ratón entre el `div` y el `p`

```
bloque.onmouseenter = cambiar;
bloque.onmouseleave = cambiar2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ordago